# How to declare a nullable object literal variable in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In typescript 2.2, when [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) option is true, how to declare a nullable object literal variable :

```
let myVar = { a: 1, b: 2 };
myVar = null; // Error can not assign null
```

The only ways I found is :

```
// Verbose
let myVar: { a: number; b: number; } | null  = { a: 1, b: 2 };

// Bad, same as having no type
let myVar: any| null  = { a: 1, b: 2 };
```

Comment: There is no way to do this. You need to explicitly declare the union type. To write less, you can define an interface for the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this by writing a `nullable` utility function:

```
const nullable = <T>(a: T) => a as T | null;

let myVar = nullable({ a: 1, b: 2 });
myVar = null; // Valid!
```

This does introduce an extra function call at variable initialization time, but likely this won't affect you much in most real world scenarios. The code is fairly clean, so I'm a fan of this solution.

---

One other not so great way to do this would be the following:

```
const fake = { a: 1, b: 2 };
let realVar: typeof fake | null = fake;
realVar = null;
```

The downsides are as follows:

- The code is somewhat cryptic to those not very familiar with TypeScript
- You have an extra runtime variable assignment for no reason
- The code still isn't that concise